# How to know which object is using a material

Tags: python, materials

How to know which object is using a material.

I know that a material is used 4 time -> picture under:[image: number object material]

I'm searching a solution with python and I'm blocked here :

```
bpy.data.materials['Y.000a'].users
```

But this function only return the number of users and not the name.

Of course the solutions, that I'm searching for, doesn't have to obligatory use python.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I wouldn't be surprised if there were a better solution, but here's what I use:

```
mat = bpy.context.object.active_material
objs = []
for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    for slot in obj.material_slots:
        if slot.material == mat:
            objs.append(obj)
```

Then `objs` will be a list of objects with the material `mat`. If you only know the material name and it's not the active material, simply replace the first line with:

```
mat = bpy.data.materials['material_name']
```

Note: This does not check if a material is assigned to any faces on the object, simply if the material is in one of the slots for that object.

Comment: You could also use `objs = {}`, and then in the `if`-statement: `if not obj in objs: objs[obj]=[slot]; else: objs[obj].append(slot)` to get a dictionary of the individual material slots, or add a counter to get the index (if required).

Answer (score 37):

The outliner is a great place to find things. Entering a string in search field located in the header not only finds items containing the string but highlights them for easy access. The search menu also offers choices for case sensitive and complete matches.

[image]

Many things can be found in the outliner - from objects and meshes to materials, textures, modifiers, vertex groups, constraints, bones and actions.

While image names used by blender internal textures can be searched, currently images used in nodes (internal or cycles) can't.

Comment: For a non-python solution, it's the best way I think. Thank you.

Comment: I want to go over all of my materials and select (or get indices of) faces to which that specific material has been applied to. I haven't been able to find a good solution for doing that as of now. I would appreciate if you can take a look at my question [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/103307/how-to-get-indices-of-the-faces-to-which-a-material-has-been-applied-to-using-p) and see if you can offer a solution?

Answer (score 7):

I have created a simple addon for this:

http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?317507-Addon-Simple-addon-to-display-material-relationships

[image]Example screen

Comment: Please provide more than a link in your answer. Can you for instance, show a screenshot of your work?

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. (If the link goes, so does the answer)

Answer (score 7):

*This isn't the best way, but for I'll post for completeness.*

---

Another quick way is to select an object which you know has the material and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>*> Material*.

This will select all the objects which use the active material of the selected object.

Comment: Thanks in my case I use multiple scene and layer so it isn't very usefull.

Comment: @lucblender It does have limitations, but it might be useful for a quick check in a one scene file. You could toggle all layers visible with the back-tick (`) key (The key below the escape key on most keyboards)

Comment: For a quick check it's the best solutions I agree with that.

Answer (score 2):

```
MNAME = 'myMaterial'
obs = [o for o in bpy.data.objects
       if type(o.data) is bpy.types.Mesh
           and MNAME in o.data.materials]
```

or

```
obs = []
for o in bpy.data.objects:
    if isinstance(o.data, bpy.types.Mesh) and MNAME in o.data.materials:
        obs.append(o)
```