# Display all users of a datablock

Tags: python, interface

How can I see all the "[users](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Data_System#Links_and_Users)" of a datablock?  Is it possible with the Blender's UI?  With Python?

For example, I'd like to know which 3 objects are the users of my material:

[image]

Comment: For that specific case you can select one object which you know has the material and press `Shift L` > Material.

Comment: For the material check this : http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4817/how-to-know-which-object-is-using-a-material

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2450/599

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Without Python:**

You can simply select one of the objects and use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> > *Material* to select all the objects that share the same material. If the object has more than one material, it'll check for the one that's currently active.

**With Python:**

It's a bit of a workaround. Each material has the attribute `users`, but this is only the number of users and not actually a list of objects/data.

So in order to get a list of all the objects that use a certain material, we have to loop through the objects, then through each object's material slots:

```
import bpy

objects = bpy.context.selectable_objects
mat = bpy.context.object.active_material

for obj in objects:
    for slot in obj.material_slots:
        if slot.material == mat:
            obj.select = True
```

Comment: Another non-python way is to search with [the outliner](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/4870/935)