# Defining Node Groups

Tags: node-editor

I will appreciate for your help.
I am creating my material library, and trying to clean and rename all materials and nodegroups.
How i can define from outliner (or any enother way) wich materials use this nodegroups

(update)

Thank you for your help. I'll try to be more specific.
Just for example. I have big scene with 105 materials, Also I have unknown node group (x) which is used by 3 users. It means that 3 materials from all 105 use this node group (x) The question is, how i can easily find these 3 materials? Where this information is shown in outliner?
[image]
Thank you

Comment: Could you clarify? I don't think there is an easy way to select by node group.

Answer (score 2):

Node Groups can be renamed either in the Properties of the Node Editor, or also in the Outliner by editing the 'Name' attribute:

[image: Editing a node group name]

(update)

How to find which are the users of some datablock (it doesn't matter if it is a material or group, the idea is the same):

The datablock itself does not store who the users are, instead you have to go over all the users and test.
See:
[How to know which object is using a material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4817/how-to-know-which-object-is-using-a-material)
[Display all users of a datablock](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13437/display-all-users-of-a-datablock)