# How can I easily check if an object is linked to an other object?

Tags: objects, edit-mode, linked-data

Sometimes I accidently make changes to an object without noticing that it is still linked to another object.
Is there a simple way to keep an eye on object links?

I couldn't find it anywhere in the properties section or in the outliner.
Right now I usually enter edit mode, zoom out and look around to see if any other object also switched to edit mode. But this method is quiet clumsy and sometimes I forget to do that and miss the link.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13437/display-all-users-of-a-datablock

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just found the answer for my question myself:

In the properties panel I have to go to the object data section. If a number is displayed beside the mesh-icon it means that the mesh of the selected object is linked to at least one other object:

[image: properties/object data]

Comment: Thanks. It's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks! I made a rightlick -> Area -> Horizontal Split to have it permanently visible my sidebar. The other way I did was using SHIFT+L -> Object Data and see if there are some linked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is why the devs are working hard to create a better management files/data system. This will yield the standard workflow we see in any other 3d package.